# I'm trying to Inherite one object from another

Tags: scala

I want to inherit one object from another:

```
object ws1 {
  object Obj1
  object Obj2 extends Obj1
}
```

It complains: `not found type Obj1`

Comment: Scala `object` has its dedicated class, but otherwise it's an object like any other one. What makes you think that inheriting from an object would make sense?

Comment: @ghik, the fact that I can't the information saying the opposite.

Comment: You can't inherit from an `object Obj` in the same way as you can't inherit from `val obj = new Object`. You can inherit only from classes and traits.

Comment: @ghik I don't have object Obj.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't inherit form objects. Change your code to the following and you should be a happier camper than before:

```
object ws1 { 
  class Obj1
  object Obj1 extends Obj1
  object Obj2 extends Obj1
}
```