# Inheritance from object Application, how do I make something similar to that?

Tags: scala

I have 3 projects included in one project, let's call them `project1`, `2` and `3` and they are included in `main project`. The `1` one is a library, whereas the `two` others are console-executable projects.

For now I have 2 pretty much identical `object Application` in the projects `2` and `3`:

```
package com.project1

abstract class Class123 extends Actor { ... }
abstract class Class456 { ... }

package com.project2

class Class123  extends package1.Class123 { ... }
class Class456  extends package1.Class456 { ... }

object Application extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem()
  val myActor = system.actorOf(Props[Class123])
  val b = new Class456               
  // some actions
}

package com.project3

class Class123  extends package1.Class123 { ... }
class Class456  extends package1.Class456 { ... }

object Application extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem()
  val myActor = system.actorOf(Props[Class123])
  val b = new Class456            
  // some actions
}
```

How do I reduce the amount of repetition? I can create `object Application` in `package1`, but it should be generic (which Scala doesn't allow to do) and I would have to inherit from it (it's not allowed by Scala either).

What do I do about it?

Comment: Already answered by your previous answerer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18773054/1296806 or, maybe you weren't aware that a class can extend App (DelayedInit) and your objects can extend that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a class instead of object:

```
class MyApp[C123, C456] extends App {
  val system = ...
  val myActor = ...
  val b = ...            
}

package com.project1
object Application1 extends MyApp[com.project1.Class123, com.project1.Class456] { 
  ... 
}

package com.project2
object Application2 extends MyApp[com.project2.Class123, com.project2.Class456] { 
  ... 
}
```